# Downloading BeautifulSoup on PyCharm

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to install BeautifulSoup package through PyCharm, I have also tried to download it through the command line. But I just cannot seem to get to it to run on PyCharm. I keep getting the following error

```
Collecting BeautifulSoup
  Using cached BeautifulSoup-3.2.1.tar.gz
    Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "C:\Users\Hemesh\AppData\Local\Temp\pycharm-packaging\BeautifulSoup\setup.py", line 22
        print "Unit tests have failed!"
                                      ^
    SyntaxError: Missing parentheses in call to 'print'

    ----------------------------------------

Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in C:\Users\Hemesh\AppData\Local\Temp\pycharm-packaging\BeautifulSoup\
You are using pip version 8.1.1, however version 8.1.2 is available.
You should consider upgrading via the 'python -m pip install --upgrade pip' command.
```

Can anyone help?

thanks in advance

Comment: What's the output of `python -V` and `pip -V`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you used to using Python 2.7? It seems to be asking for Python 3.X syntax for your print statement, so it might be an issue with the versions you're trying to use?

BeautifulSoup 3.2.1 only works with Python 2.7 (and is obsolete), if you get BeautifulSoup 4, it should work with both versions.

Comment: I'm running on python 3. I've tried to install and re-install python. But for some strange reason I cannot seem to install python 3.

Comment: I just edited my comment, but BeautifulSoup 3.2.1 should not work Python 3